# JavaScript simple two input calculator best approach - clear inputs, add alert and comma

Tags: javascript, input, calculator, calculation

I am creating a simple two input JavaScript calculation. Can someone please tell me if this is correct or if there is a better way to do it. Also trying to clear my input fields after my calculation and add a comma to my output number, but it's not working. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated? Thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Monthly discount</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
      1st Input : <input type="text" class="input" id="firstNumber" />
      2nd Input: <input type="text" class="input" id="secondNumber" /><br>
      <input type="button" onClick="calculateNums()" Value="Show Discount"/>
    </form>
    <span id="result"></span>
<script>
    function clearInput(){
        const clearFields = document.querySelectorAll('input').value = "";
        return clearFields;
    }
    function calculateNums(avgGallonsPerWeek, fillUpsPerWeek) {
        const num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
        const num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
        const number1_parsed = parseInt(firstNumber.value);
        const number2_parsed = parseInt(secondNumber.value);
        const monthly = 4;// 4 weeks in a month
        const costPerGall = 5.00; //5.00 per gallon
        const discount = .15; //monthly discount 15%
        const multAll = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "$" + number1_parsed * number2_parsed * monthly * costPerGall * discount + " in savings";
        clearInput();
    }
    // This is what I am doing with my calculations -
    //(315 miles per fillup) x (5 times per week) x (4 weeks in a month) x (5 per gallon) x (.15% discount)
    //Why is my clear inputs not working after my calculation?
    //Want to add an alert if a number is not an integer?

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It is working, but I need to clear my inputs after it calculates and add a comma to my output number. Want to add an alert if a number is not an integer.

Comment: Please use `parseInt` [_with_ the second parameter, `10`](/q/16880327/4642212). Consider using [`Number`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Function_syntax) or [`parseFloat`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead, or, specifically for `<input>`s, [`.valueAsNumber`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `calculateNums()` function, which you call on "Show Discount" button click, takes two arguments, which are never used in the function, and which you also do not provide the values for. It has no effect on your code, but it's just bad practice to include meaningless stuff in your code.

Second, the `clearInput` function should return void, meaning return no result, so you should not return the result of this `document.querySelectorAll('input').value = "";`. You also should not try to clear all inputs this way, because `querySelectorAll` will also select your button `<input type="button" onClick="calculateNums()" Value="Show Discount"/>`. I suggest you change the clearInput function to something like below:

```
function clearInput() {
    document.getElementById('firstNumber').value = "";
    document.getElementById('secondNumber').value = "";
}
```

Third, I did not test this, but [1LOC](https://1loc.dev/validator/check-if-a-value-is-a-number/) says you can use something like the method below to check if the provided input is a number:

```
function validateInputNumber(value) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(value)) && isFinite(value);
}
```

Then you can call that from your `calculateNums` function.

There are more things to improve, such as explaining your algorithm, as well as what you're even trying to calculate. It's good that you name things, but it's not clear (at least to me) what your calculation is supposed to calculate.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atnz06L8/15/)

Comment: Thank you Pzelenovic. This is what I am doing with my calculations -
(If a driver fills up 315 gallons per fill up) x (5 times per week) x (4 weeks in a month) x (Avg $5.00 per gallon) x (.15% discount). My algorithm provides the average discount in fuel savings per month. Forgot to remove my two arguments from calculateNums function as well as they are never used. Everything is working as intended now. Appreciate your help and advice.

Comment: Could you please clarify what are the two inputs for then? The `firstNumber` and the `secondNumber` fields?

Comment: If the two input fields are for `gallonsPerFillUp` and `fillupsPerWeek` then you could do something like the following https://jsfiddle.net/6sux2h5a/53/